# Errors at Python program exit: "close failed in file object destructor"; "sys.excepthook is missing"

Tags: python, linux, sys

After the last line (print statement) in my python code, I get the following error:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Anyone know where this might be coming from?

Update: My python code is extremely long but I will post portions that may have something to do with this error:

For one, near the beginning of the process I redirect stdout and stderr to a log file like this:

```
so = se = open(logfile, 'w', 0)                       
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0) 
os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())           
os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
```

I do this all the time though and have never run into this error but it seems the most likely reason I'm seeing this.

Comment: What do you do with the error (`stderr`) stream when you call the program?

Comment: Are you importing any modules you wrote yourself named `sys`?

Comment: I think the error might be coming from your code, but since you haven't shown us any of it, the world may never know.

Comment: @jwodder hah well, the code is super long and i don't know which parts are relevant to this error so that's why i didn't post anything

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please see the edit to my post

Comment: Validate that the portion you post is actually **sufficient to reproduce the problem**. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the rules on creating a **M**inimal, **C**omplete, **V**erifiable **E**xample. Yes, this means you need to do some work yourself before asking your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the following statement to the very end of my main function fixes this issue for me:

```
try:
    sys.stdout.close()
except:
    pass
try:
    sys.stderr.close()
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

Doing flush and close worked for me.

```
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.close()

sys.stderr.flush()
sys.stderr.close()
```

Comment: The answer by user20408  works for me. This answer works too and sheds light with a new error message: `sys.stdout.flush()
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`